# DataProvider mismatch Exception

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

Getting DataProvider mismatch exception. Below is the code can anyone help me? My Excel file is having 6 values where I am passing the same amount of values from the Excel.

```
package newtoursProject;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test_file2 {
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"param1","param2","param3"})
    void environment(String sg1,String sg2,String sg3)
    {
        System.setProperty(sg1, sg2);
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(sg3);    


    }
    @Parameters({"param4","param5"})
    @Test(priority=1)
    void login(String sn,String sn2)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.name(ObjectRepository.s1)).sendKeys(sn);
        driver.findElement(By.name(ObjectRepository.s2)).sendKeys(sn2);
        driver.findElement(By.name(ObjectRepository.s3)).click();

    }
    @Test(dataProvider="fb")
    void flight(String s1,String s2,String s5,String s6,String s7,String s8)
    {   
        System.out.println("Hello");
    radio(s1,s2);
    System.out.println("Hello");
    //dropdown(s3,s4);
    dropdown(s5,s6);
    dropdown(s7,s8);
    }
    public void dropdown(String a,String b)
    {
        WebElement dropdown=driver.findElement(By.name(a)); 
        Select obj= new Select(dropdown);
        obj.selectByVisibleText(b);

    }
    public void radio(String a,String b)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        List<WebElement> radio=driver.findElements(By.name(a)); 

        System.out.println(radio);
        for(WebElement temp:radio)
        {
            if(temp.getAttribute("value").contains(b))
            {
                //System.out.println("Hello");
                temp.click();
            }
        }
    }

    String[][] getDataExcel(String filename,String sheetname) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(filename);

        HSSFWorkbook wbk=new HSSFWorkbook(fin);
        HSSFSheet sheet=wbk.getSheet(sheetname);
        int rowsize=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
        int colsize=sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println(rowsize);
        System.out.println(colsize);
        HSSFRow row;
        HSSFCell  cell;
        String ar[][]=new String[rowsize][colsize];
        for(int i=0;i<rowsize;i++)
        {
             row=sheet.getRow(i);
            for(int j=0;j<colsize;j++)
            {
                cell=row.getCell(j);
                ar[i][j]=cell.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+"\t");

            }
            System.out.println();

        }
        return ar;

    }
    @DataProvider(name="fb")
    Object[][] Registration() throws IOException
    {
        Object[][] str=getDataExcel("C:\\Users\\sailu\\Desktop\\NewTours_project.xls","Sheet1");
        return str;

    }

}
```

Using TestNG framework and using dataprovider reading data from Excel 
and passing the same values as specified in the test.
Please help

Exception:
I am getting the following exception..

flight org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: Data provider mismatch Method: flight([Parameter{index=0, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=2, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=3, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=4, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=5, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}]) Arguments: [(java.lang.String) tripType,(java.lang.String) oneway] ... Removed 20 stack frames

Comment: Hello, attach more information start with the exception :)

Comment: @sailusha share exception details